# How to change the default filter operator in kendo ui grid mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, grid, kendo-ui

I have managed to change the default filter order for the Kendo Grid using:

```
.Filterable(filterable => filterable
                        .Extra(true)
                        .Operators(ops => 
                            ops.ForString(str => str.Clear()
                                                    .Contains("Contains")
                                                    .StartsWith("Starts with")
                                                    .EndsWith("Ends with")
                                                    .IsEqualTo("Is equal to"))
                        ))
```

Is there any way I can change the default operator to OR?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done via the [filterMenuInit](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid/#events-filterMenuInit) event:

```
 /* grid configuration snip */
.Events(e => e.FilterMenuInit("filterMenuInit"))
 /* grid configuration snip */

 <script>
 function filterMenuInit(e) {
      e.container
         .find("select.k-filter-and")
         .data("kendoDropDownList")
         .value("or");
 }
 </script>
```

Here is a live demo: http://jsbin.com/etItEpi/1/edit

Comment: Unfortunately this solution is only partially working, and cause a very disturbing user experience: After reordering the column, the operator resets back to 'And'. To reproduce this: 1) configure the grid/column in the sample to sortable, 2) Run, 3) Click on the filter and note the operator is 'Or'. 4) Reorder the column by clicking on its header 5) Click on the filter, and note the operator is reset to its default: 'And'.

Comment: @g.pickardou or just press the Clear button.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this on a per column basis on your grid definition (MVC):

```
cols.Bound(m => m.xxx).Filterable(f=> f.Cell(cell => cell.Operator("or")));
```

Comment: This does not seem to work. No compile error, no runtime error, however the default And operation remains

Comment: This is for the `GridFilterMode.Row` filter mode

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I've also been struggling with it recently. Here is my solution:

```cs
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<GridModel>()
  .Name("GridName")
  .Filterable(settings => settings
      .Mode(GridFilterMode.Menu)
      .Extra(true))
  .Events(e => e.FilterMenuInit("filterMenuInit"))
  .Columns(...)
  .DataSource(...))
```

```js
<script>
    function filterMenuInit(e) {
        if (e.field === 'MyField') {
            var header = e.sender.thead.find('th[data-field=MyField]'),
                filterMenu = header.data('kendoFilterMenu'),
                filterModel = filterMenu['filterModel'];

            //change the logic operator
            filterModel.set('logic', 'or');

            //change the first operator to "greater than or equal to"
            filterModel.set('filters[0].operator', 'gte');

            //change the second operator to "less than or equal to"
            filterModel.set('filters[1].operator', 'lte');
        }
    }
</script>
```

Find more [here](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/mvvm/observableobject).